# How can I find and edit/delete links from a Word document before JS requirement set 1.4?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm developing a MS Word Add-In using the JS API. Currently, I need to find and edit or delete specific links inside the entire document. I know that this works using `context.document.body.fields` and then `item.result.delete()` and `item.result.insertText('new text', 'Replace')`. But `context.document.body.fields` is only available in the latest versions of Word (technically since requirement set 1.4).

I just want to know, are there alternative ways to do this in older Word versions before rs 1.4? And if so, what are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use document.body.search() method to find the hyperlink and this method will return a Range object, you can futher call something like InsertText() to replace it or call range.hyperlink = "" to remove the hyperlink.

Comment: Okay, replacing the link text using `range.insertText()` works fine. Using `range.hyperlink` requires rs 1.3, though. In the end I only need to remove the entire link (incl. the text). Is this possible in rs 1.1, too? Removing only the text inside the link isn't enough because an empty link seems to keep existing in the document.

Comment: I think you can further try range.delete() or range.clear method to remove the hyperlink.

Comment: I'll test both possibilities again tomorrow, but what I've tried resulted in an empty, invisible link being left in the document.

Comment: No, both `range.delete()` and `range.clear()` only remove the linked text but not the link itself. Since the add-in I'm developing shows a list of all links in the document the link is visible (without text) in this list which will definitely confuse users.

Comment: This is what I see: I select the whole hyperlink and call context.document.getzSelection().delete(), the hyperlink is fully deleted and I didn't see any links left. Anyway, if this is not working for you, I am afraid you will need to use the Filed related APIs.

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand what you mean. But our add-in operates on all links in the document in an automated way using `document.body.search()`. But nevermind. If it doesn't work, there's nothing that can be done. We can only tell our customer that the requested feature requires specific Word versions. That's fine. Thank you for your help.